# Verify complete certificate chain being sent by Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

I have configured my Apache web server to send out the complete SSL certificate chain and now I want to verify that the the complete chain is, in fact, being sent.

I would normally use something like `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect servername:443 -verify 10` to verify that the entire certificate chain is coming through. However, in this instance I cannot do that as the web site I want to check is behind a web-based SSO (single-sign on) system that prevents using a command-line tool.

Is there an Apache log setting that will explicitly show me which certificates are being sent by Apache? Alternately, is there a browser plugin I could use to see which certificates are being sent by the server?

Comment: Is the site accessible to the public? Can you simply use one of the online scanners like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest to check? -edit- sorry, I just noticed you mentioned it is behind something.

Comment: what do you mean by 'is behind a SSO (single-sign on) system' ?

Comment: The SSO is web-based and is very difficult to work around from the command-line.